# Forms Authentication in MVC 3 fails in Safari / production

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using Forms Authentication in MVC 3 and all works great on my development workstation, but when I post to the production environment authentication fails... but ONLY for Safari. It works great in IE, Firefox and Chrome, but not Safari.

Any pointer would be most appreciated!

EDIT:

It seems that setting a non-persistent cookie works:

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, false);

So this would appear to be something to do with the expiry date?

Anything particular about expiry date and Safari?

Comment: I get this error too, but it has nothing to do with MVC, I think it's just Forms Authentication in general with Safari.  And if other posts are correct it's not just Safari on a Mac but also on Windows.  Another guy on Stack Overflow manually set the authentication by making the ticket instead of using SetAuthCookie and he says it works.

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET Forms Authentication with Windows Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531645/asp-net-forms-authentication-with-windows-safari)